# Evaluate function if the result appears to be outside the domain?

Tags: functions, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I've been given a transformation $f,$ from $P_2$ to $P_2$ (the vector space of polynomials of maximum degree $2$) such that
$$f(p(x)) = p(x+1) +\int_{0}^{1} p(x)dx.$$
Here, $p(x)$ is just a polynomial in the vector space

Working with respect to the basis $\left\{1,x,x^2\right\}$, it appears as though when $p(x) =x^2$, that integral would be $\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot x^3$. Clearly, $x^3$ is of degree $3$ so is outside of the vector space.

Is my thinking correct? And how would I apply this to making a matrix with respect to the basis given?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x^2)=(x+1)^2+\int_0^1x^2dx=(x+1)^2+\left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_0^1=(x+1)^2+\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

The integral part is a *definite* integral, so results in a constant, but you have it as the *indefinite* integral.